# Python: How to check if an entry already exists in a sql database?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm new to python and even newer to sql, but I have been trying to make this work all morning and I cannot seem to figure it out. I have a table setup called POSTS(id). I'm trying to check if a number is already in the id column, but it doesn't matter what number postid is because data never returns none even if postid is set to a number not in the database.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('post.db')
postid = '52642'

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select id from POSTS where id=?", (postid,))
data = cur.fetchall()
if data is None:
        print ('not found')
else:
        print ('found')
```

Comment: BTW, `'52642'` is not a number; `52642` is. But you are likely to be saved by [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Answer (score 7):

The statement

```
data = cur.fetchall()
```

will assign to `data` an empty list, **not** `None`, when nothing is found.

So just change your check to:

```
if not data:
```

instead of:

```
if data is None:
```

Comment: Similarly you can use 'if data == []'

Comment: @Freestyle076, yes, but `if not data:` is faster -- and, not surprising, a more Pythonic idiom (Python's implementation tends to be optimized to make more idiomatic expressions faster).